# How can I fetch and share posts by "ids" for different webpages in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Having three different pages and 100 posts, how can one fetch latest posts shared on these three pages? 30 posts (ID -> 100 to 71) for page 1, 30 posts (ID -> 70 to 41) for page 2 and 40 posts (ID -> 40 to 1) for page 3. Is this possible? I have been able to achieve only the first part like this:

```
$page1 = Post::with('author')->latest()->take(30)->get(); // This gave me exactly 30 latest posts
```

Also, I would like to apply pagination but don’t know how to chain it along with what I have.

I would so much appreciate a help here. Thanks.

Comment: The [manual on Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination) didn't help? `Post::with('author')->latest()->paginate(30);` should do it

Comment: At@kerb0lz. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. Well the manual on pagination helped but my main concern is how to share the 100 posts on three pages like I posted in my question.

Comment: If you want to share 100 posts on 3 pages, you first have a problem: 100/3 is 33.3. So you either round it to 90 to get 30 posts per page and it doesn't matter how many pages you show, it always 30 posts per page. I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57333748/1653305) might help.

Comment: What happens if posts get added or deleted? Should page1 & page2 always show 30 items? What if there are only 29 posts total?

Comment: At@kerbh0lz, good question. It doesn’t have to be 30 items. It could be less due to deletion. Could laravel throw an error if an item among the 30 is deleted? And these pages have their specific routes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, what you are looking for is Pagination.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#introduction

Typically, pagination works by taking the requested amount and displaying that number of results. If there aren't that number available it will display as many as it can.

In your scenario, it would be 30,30,30,10 rather than 30,30,40.

Again, a typical use of pagination would be to use a single page but use `GET` parameters in the URL to switch the content of the pages. i.e.

```
https://mydomain/index?page=1
https://mydomain/index?page=2
https://mydomain/index?page=3
```

The part of the documation which covers this is here:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Comment: At@Spholt. Thanks a lot. Actually, pagination is not the real issue, however, fault on my side as my question wasn’t well phrased. My aim is 30 posts for page 1 and paginating it to 5 posts per display. Same goes for page 2 and 3. Basically, having 100 posts spread on three specific pages by their IDs. Hope you understand. 100 - 71 on page 1 (paginates by 5), 70 - 41 on page 2 (paginates by 5) and 40 - 1 on page 3 (paginates by 5). That’s exactly my aim.

Comment: Seems like an odd scenario but the same principles would still apply. Constrain your query to those posts you want using normal `->where()` type clauses and then call `->paginate(5)` rather than `->get()` and it should work the same

Answer (score 0):

Finally here’s what I came up with and it worked just as I intended.

I declared query scopes in my Post model like this:

```
public function scopeLoadThirty($query)
{
 return $query->whereBetween(‘id’, [71, 100]);
}

public function scopeLoadNextThirty($query)
{
 return $query->whereBetween(‘id’, [41, 70]);
}

public function scopeLoadFinal($query)
{
 return $query->whereBetween(‘id’, [1, 40]);
}
```

Then in my Post controller in index methods, I queried like this...

```
use App\Post;

public function indexOne()
{
 $page1 = Post::LoadThirty()->with(‘authors’)->where(‘category’, ‘Catering’)->latest()->paginate(5);

return view(‘posts.indexOne‘, compact(‘page1’));
}

public function indexTwo()
{
 $page2 = Post::LoadNextThirty()->with(‘authors’)->where(‘category’, ‘Engineering’)->latest()->paginate(5);

return view(‘posts.indexTwo’, compact(‘page2’));
}

public function indexThree()
{
 $page3 = Post::LoadFinal()->with(‘authors’)->where(‘category’, ‘Tech’)->latest()->paginate(5);

return view(‘posts.indexThree’, compact(‘page3’));
}
```

This worked exactly as I had in mind.