# When building pagination, how do I know if there is a next page or not?

Tags: database, pagination

Let's say I'm trying to build out a pagination system for one of my tables in my database. For this example, assume the following:

- The table has `x` rows.
- Each page should contain 50 items.

Now, let's say I hit my API and ask for the first page of items. It's simple enough to return the first 50 rows from the total `x`, but I'm trying to understand how the system understands if there is a next page or not.

Am I supposed to get the total number of rows and see if that exceeds `{page_number} * 50`? Moreover, is there a non-negligible performance penalty for doing it this way?

I apologize if this question comes off as silly, but I'm generally used to frameworks and tools that do this automatically, so I'm trying to understand what happens under the hood. Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Even if this is not a silly question, but: why not check out any framework that supports pagination and debug what is happening

Comment: For example, https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/tutorials/pagination.html provides insights about Doctrine, an ORM for PHP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324838/how-does-laravels-pagination-work-exactly contains information about Laravel's pagination support

Comment: If you only need to know, is there next page or not, you can fetch 51 rows, return 50 rows to client and if there are 51 rows fetched, then there is next page too. If you need to know total pages count, then yes, you have to query records count (at least once, if count doesn't change).